# Liquibase - how add changelog for second database in play framework with play-slick

Tags: scala, playframework, configuration, liquibase, slick

I have one database with changelog. My application.conf:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile = "models.database.CustomPostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "postgres"
slick.dbs.default.db.password = "postgres"

liquibase = ${slick.dbs.default.db}
liquibase.changelog = "classpath:liquibase/changelog-master.xml"
```

Then i add second database with different schema:

```
slick.dbs.db2.profile = "models.database.CustomPostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.db2.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.db2.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb2"
slick.dbs.db2.db.user = "postgres"
slick.dbs.db2.db.password = "postgres"
```

How i can add changelog-master-db2.xml for second database? Or specify target database for changeSet in main changelog-master.xml.

I use: scala 2.12.6, play-slick 3.0.1, play-liquibase 1.4

Answer (score 0):

It is suggest to make use of liquibase.properties file where you can mention the two database properties and the changelog file in one liquibase.properties file. You can find all the details about the liquibase.properties file on [this page](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html)